# VBA delete cell below last pasted range

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

```
Sheets("MDCF").Select
Range("B6:B100").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Replace What:="10000", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("J6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MDCF Fund").Select
Range("F7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

With Sheets("MDCF Fund")
        Set FOUNDRANGE = .Columns("F:F").Find("*", After:=.Range("F81"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, 
  LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not FOUNDRANGE Is Nothing Then LR1 = FOUNDRANGE.Row
End With
    Range("F80:F" & LR1 + 1).Select
Selection.Clear
```

I am trying to delete the cells that are below last cell in new sheet but its not working if the cell range is same in both copy paste ranges. trying to find a way in which I will be able to delete only redundant cell that are above F80 and below the copied cell counts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to straight away delete all the data after F80 then the below code would work,

```
    With Sheets("MDCF Fund")
    LR1 = Range("F" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row

   'If you want to keep the cells between the pasted data and F80 then just add the IF condition
    If (LR1 > 80) Then
        Range("F80:F" & LR1).Select
        Selection.clear
    end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After copy paste I may have redundant cells above F80 and below last pasted cell which I want to keep. Isnt finding  "end xlup"  will come LR1 as last redundant cell?